# Transactional Replication breaks when schema is changed in Publisher

Tags: replication, transactional-replication, snapshot

We have set up Transactional replication where two Publishers feed into one Subscriber. Now if try to change the schema of any one Publisher or both publishers, replication breaks.

We have tried to pause the replication and change the schema in publisher as well as subscriber, but as soon as we re-start the replication it breaks.

The only option that we found is, we have to drop the replication, sync the schema and the start the snapshot replication.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I presume this question should be tagged with SQL Server or similar.

Answer (score 1):

From [Make Schema Changes on Publication Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/make-schema-changes-on-publication-databases):

> Schema changes to tables must be made by using Transact-SQL or SQL Server Management Objects (SMO). When schema changes are made in SQL Server Management Studio, Management Studio attempts to drop and re-create the table. You cannot drop published objects, therefore the schema change fails.